# Multiple databases are seen in data folder Android

Tags: android, database, eclipse

I have found one strange thing while exploring files from Eclipse during my application run.
Up till now I was seeing just one databases folder in file explorer while running my app on emulator.Now it shows as following:[image: Multiple databases folders]

Is this a problem of **Emulator or Eclipse** 
I can't figure out or really this many databases are generated?

Currently I am using **Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse Juno**.

I am just creating Database Object in first activity:

```
Database db = new Database(Home.this);
```

Where as Database contains:

```
    public Database(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
     if(DBHelper == null)
        {
         DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

}
```

Comment: Try delete your avd and recreate it.

Comment: Solution : Try delete your avd and recreate it. Reason : Can't Say.